# In terms of $a, b,$ and $\theta$, what is the biased $b(\hat \theta)$?

Tags: statistics, expectation, statistical-inference, estimation

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $\{P_{\theta}: \theta \in \Theta \}$ be a statistical model. Suppose that $\hat \theta$ is an estimator for a parameter $\theta$ and $E_{\theta}(\hat \theta) = a\theta + b$ for given non-zero constants $a$ and $b$.

(a) In terms of $a, b,$ and $\theta$, what is the biased $b(\hat \theta)$?

(b) Use the estimator $\hat \theta$ to construct an unbiased estimator for $\theta$.

**Where I Am:**

This problem just seems a little too easy...

For part (a), all I did was the following:

$$b(\hat \theta) = E[\hat \theta] - \theta \quad \text{(by definition)} $$

so

$$ b(\hat \theta) = (a\theta + b) - \theta \quad \text{(by what was provided)}$$

which, I guess, can be simplified to

$$ b(\hat \theta) = \theta(a-1) + b $$

but, aside from that, I'm not sure if there's any more to it?

Now, for part (b), we need to satisfy the following condition:

$$ E[\hat \theta] = \theta. $$

Ok. Well, that simply means the following, I guess:

$$ a\theta + b = \theta $$

and then solving for $\theta$:

$$ \hat \theta = \frac{-b}{a-1}. $$

Is that it? Am I missing something?

Comment: The second question, I believe, means "construct $\tilde{\theta} = f(\hat{\theta})$ such that $\tilde{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$".

Comment: Hmm. I see. That makes more sense. However, I'm not quite sure how to proceed now...

Comment: Since only the expectation of $\hat{\theta}$ was given, $f$ has to be a linear function (otherwise the problem be unsolvable). Consider the expectation of $\tilde{\theta} = \alpha \hat{\theta} + \beta$.

Comment: Ok. Well, $E[\tilde \theta] = E[\alpha \hat \theta + \beta] = \alpha E[\hat \theta] + \beta = \alpha(a\theta+b) + \beta$. Am I supposed to just solve this for $\theta$ and put a hat on it and call it my unbiased estimator?

Comment: No, solve $\alpha (a \theta + b) + \beta = \theta$ (for all $\theta$) for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then the unbiased estimator is $\alpha \hat{\theta} + \beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E(\hat \theta) = a\theta + b,$ then 
$\tilde \theta = \frac{\hat \theta - b}{a}$ is unbiased.

I can't immediately think of a simple example that has both
$a \ne 1$ and $b \ne 0$. So here are two separate examples
where $b = 0$, since $a$ is the part that seems to be giving
you trouble.

Consider using independent observations $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$
from $Unif(0, \theta)$ to estimate $\theta.$
You might consider estimator $\bar X.$
Because $E(\bar X) = \theta/2$, an unbiased estimator is $2\bar X.$

Alternatively, you might consider the maximum observation $X_{(n)}$
as an estimator. Because $E(X_{(n)}) = \frac{n}{n+1}\theta$,
the estimator $\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$ is unbiased for $\theta.$

Between these two, the estimator $\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$ has the
smaller variance, so it is preferable. Indeed, one can show
that, among unbiased estimators, this one has the smallest
possible variance. You have many interesting ideas coming if
this course is at the level I suspect.